# Push notifications not work in iOS production with cordova-plugin-fcm plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, push

I am developing an application with ionic, cordova for iOS platform.
Everything on Android is fine. Also the iOS application works only with the certified developer.

The problem is when I upload the app to the app store using the certified distribution. Do not receive notifications on my device.

I also have the apns developer and distribution uploaded to firebase.

**The following solutions did not work for me:**

https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=production

Comment: Did you enable push notifications in Xcode (located in the Capabilities pane in the project editor for your target)?

Comment: @JanP Yes! Enable the option in compatibilities but only 1 check appears.

- Steps: Add the "Push Notifications" entitlement to your App ID

I was seeing in other examples 2 selected checks appear
What is the other check necessary for??

Comment: As far as I know it's just push notifications. Maybe background modes, but I don't think so. I will add this as an answer...

Comment: @JanP Ok, it's fine. This problem is very rare

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enable Push Notifications in Xcode (App > Capabilities).

For more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device

Comment: Yes! Enable the option in compatibilities but only 1 check appears: - Steps: Add the "Push Notifications" entitlement to your App ID I was seeing in other examples 2 selected checks appear What is the other check necessary for??

Comment: @JulioMachado I'm working on a Windows machine right now, so no opportunity to check, but as far as I know, we also have one checkbox. And it works for our apps.